# Access service via custom HTTPS port using nginx-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

When using `nginx-ingress` in Kubernetes, how can I define a custom port which should be used for HTTPS, instead of 443? My configuration looks as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2019-04-17T14:15:25Z"
  generation: 3
  name: foo
  namespace: foo
  resourceVersion: "1535141"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/foo/ingresses/foo
  uid: f1b4dae9-6072-1239-a12a-fa161aff25ae
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: foo
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: foo-ingress-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
```

Preferably, I would like to be able to access the service via HTTPS on both the default 443 port and an additional custom port.

Comment: Hi, i am not sure about nginx but this one allow you to choose custom port https://appscode.com/products/voyager/8.0.1/guides/ingress/http/custom-http-port/

Comment: Thank you for you input! Unfortunately I'm forced to use the ingress nginx controller.

Comment: Yea, As ingress is designed for http & https.  for non-http we need to use service type=LoadBalancer if you are on the cloud

Comment: @SureshVishnoi I still would like to use HTTPS, it's not that I would like to use a different protocol. I would just like to expose HTTPS via port 443 and, let's say, 6443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in ingress-nginx it is impossible to listen to more than one HTTPS port. You can change HTTPS port number using --https-port command line argument, but there can only be one HTTPS port.

Comment: That would mean to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809893/expose-service-on-custom-port-via-https-on-gke?noredirect=1#comment116356636_65809893 I would need two NGINX-ingress (controllers)?

Comment: In realty, you can add a server snippet, filled with an nginx directive, to your ingress to listen on a custom port. Then, add that port to your deployment/daemonset and service and you should achieve your goal.